# KNN value of K based on labels

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

I have two questions regarding KNN.

Q1. If training data have 7 classes should I consider higher K (for example I start with k=14?).

Q2. Since half of my training data is not labeled I will be using self training.

Self training Algorithm works as follows:

```
•Let L be the set of labeled data, U be the set of unlabeled data.

•Repeat

– Train a classifier h with training data L

 – Classify data in U with h

 – Find a subset U’ of U with the most confident scores.

 – L + U’ -> L

 – U – U’ -> U
```

What is considered confident scores here? For each training data, is it the percent of the chosen class's occurrence compared to to other classes in the k neighbor of that training data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1. If training data have 7 classes should I consider higher K (for
>   example I start with k=14?).

The parameter $k$ in nearest neighbours is usually picked via $n
$-fold cross-validation. [See this question for further details.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126051/choosing-optimal-k-for-knn)

> Q2. Since half of my training data is not labeled I will be using self
>   training, what is considered a confident scores here?

Although kNN predicts the label for a new datapoint $x$ by simple majority vote, [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934203/probability-of-a-k-nearest-neighbor-like-classification) the majority vote also approximates the probability for each posterior label $l$ as given by
$$
P(l \mid x) = \frac{\text{number of k-nearest neighbour labelled } l }{k}.
$$
You can use this as your confidence score.